# Adding custom theme - scss

Tags: css, extjs4, sass, extjs4.1

i am getting this error;

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: ext4/default/all.
              Load paths:
                C:/xampp/htdocs/proj/app/resources/sass
                E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
                E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
                Compass::SpriteImporter
        on line 8 of C:/xampp/htdocs/proj/app/resources/sass/my-ext-theme.scss
```

In the `C:/xampp/htdocs/proj/app/resources/sass/my-ext-theme.scss` file, my line 8 looks like;

```
@import 'ext4/default/all';
```

I am clueless as what is causing this issue. Can someone guide me to what i am doing wrong ?

**UPDATE**

EXTJS file is placed in **app/extjs**

Then ;
**SASS**
app/resources/sass/my-ext-theme.scss
app/resources/sass/config.rb

**CSS**
app/resources/css/my-ext-theme.css

**THE COMMAND I USED TO COMPILE**

\app\resources > **compass compile**

Comment: Pretty self explanatory, it means it cannot find, or read that file.

Comment: Yes, i know. Even if the file is there i am getting this error. and that is why i posted this question.

Comment: We need more information, where is the file on you file system? What command are you running? What folder are you running the command in?

Comment: i have updated my post above.